# Revert (cancel) changes to entity of SpringData repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have SpringData Repository that can be used for commiting updates of entity:

```
entity=(E) repository.save(entity);
repository.flush();
```

What is the best practice to cancel updates, revert chagnes to entity? I can image that one can discard entity and read it once from database. But previous experience tells us that those operations usually come in pairs - transaction commit/rollback, save/cancel, etc. Maybe JPA and SpringData have something for save and flush as well?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `flush`, because a [flush is automatically triggered](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-flush-strategies/) by:

- commit
- an entity query (HQL/Criteria)

The only time when you need to manually flush the Session is [before executing native queries](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-dark-side-of-hibernate-auto-flush/) or when you want to customize the [flush operation order](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-knowing-flush-operations-order-matters/).

If you enrol all operations in a single transaction, cancelling means rolling back the transaction, since each transaction runs in isolation (unless you use READ_UNCOMMITTED).

If you want to provide a compensation action support, you might want to adopt a [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), which allows you to implement an undo mechanism.

Another interesting pattern is the CQRS architecture style, which allows you to separate writes from reads. Each write is encapsulated in an Event object that gets saved in a dedicated event store. A separate EventHandler process evaluates incoming events and execute the associated event logic.

This design style allows you to supply compensating events to revert previously executed actions.